openssl token for strapi
how to make openssl token work for strapi?
I created an created openssl token using commamd:
openssl rand -base64 24
when using the generated token to call a service, iam getting 401 unauthorised error - "Invalid token: token did not contain required fields"
Please guide.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
